# Unable to use OpenVPN Access Server admin page on google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, openvpn, google-cloud-vpn

I deployed the service called `OpenVPN Access Server` in my Google Cloud Instance and now it looks like this:

[OpenVPN Access Server instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QiHU.jpg)

When I try to open the url of the site address, says `Your connection is not private` ... It can not connect because I have no ssl and no domain configured, and if I try to change `https` to `http`, it says `This site can’t be reached` and it's because port 80 is not listening in the VM deployed.

Can any one help me with this?

Comment: After installing OpenVPN, did you follow the quick start to set up OpenVPN?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @arao6 yes I did! it was just typing 'thisisunsafe' on keyboard.